# Deserialize JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am having a problem deserializing a json object because it does not consist of an array.

A sample of the json string :

```
 {
  "Data": {
    "A1": {
      "name": "",
      "code": "",      
      "type": ""
    },
    "A2": {
     "name": "",
      "code": "",      
      "type": ""
    },
    "A3": {
      "name": "",
      "code": "",      
      "type": ""
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my code, the json string will be read from a file, and cannot be changed.

```
var json = "{\"Data\":{\"A1\":{\"name\":\"\",\"code\":\"\",\"type\":\"\"},\"A2\":{\"name\":\"\",\"code\":\"\",\"type\":\"\"},\"A3\":{\"name\":\"\",\"code\":\"\",\"type\":\"\"}}}";
var jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataContainer>(json);


public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }            
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class DataContainer
{
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Only way I have managed to do this is by changing the json to use an array like the sample below, but I would hope to solve this without having to change the format of the json file.

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "code": "",      
      "type": ""
    },
    {
     "name": "",
      "code": "",      
      "type": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "",
      "code": "",      
      "type": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your json contains a Data object which contains three different objects: A1, A2, A3.

So I think you need to implement three different classes, and a container

```
public class A1
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class A2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class A3
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public A1 A1 { get; set; }
    public A2 A2 { get; set; }
    public A3 A3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Was afraid of this, there will be hundreds of these objects which have the same structure, was hoping to do it without creating a class for every single one of them

Comment: Thanks, was just trying to avoid a lengthy discussion with the other party which set up the json file.

Comment: btw I suggest to use a tool like http://json2csharp.com/ to generate your c# classes

Comment: @BartKooi You don't need a separate class for each item; just use one class for the data and a dictionary to hold them.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I created 2 classes and manually deserialize the json object like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = "{\"Data\":{\"A1\":{\"name\":\"\",\"code\":\"\",\"type\":\"\"},\"A2\":{\"name\":\"\",\"code\":\"\",\"type\":\"\"},\"A3\":{\"name\":\"\",\"code\":\"\",\"type\":\"\"}}}";
        var data = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject).First.First;

        List<DataItem> list = new List<DataItem>();
        foreach (var item in data.ToList())
        {
            list.Add(new DataItem()
            {
                Name = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)(item)).Name,
                A = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(item.First.ToString())
            });
        }
    }

    class DataItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } //A1, A2, A3 ....
        public A A { get; set; }
    }

    class A
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your original JSON data format, change the definition of your `DataContainer` class to use a `Dictionary<string, Data>` instead of a `List<Data>`:

```
public class DataContainer
{
    public Dictionary<string, Data> Data { get; set; }
}
```